# Calling private method from another class, violating Encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation

On [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/reflection6) example is presented a way how to call a private method of class A, from another class?

Since on "regular way" we can not use this, is this violating of encapsulation?

Comment: Go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses

Answer (score 2):

Yes its a violation. And that is one of the reasons why you should carefully use Reflection. For more look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002904/what-is-the-security-risk-of-object-reflection). It can be somewhat controlled by using [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, and using reflection is explicitly a means of evading the usual access controls. If it's really important to prevent this, you can install a `SecurityManager` that limits reflection.