# How to access dynamiclly variables from another Java Class?

Tags: java, android, xml

My question similar to others but it's little bit more tricky for me
I have a Class DummyData having static defined variables

1. public static String Survey_1="";
2. public static String Survey_2="";
3. public static String Survey_3="";

So, i call them DummyData.Survey_1 and it returns whole string value. Similarly do with DummyData.Survey_2 and DummyData.Survey_3
But the problem is when i call them Dynamically its not return their value.
I have a variable data which value is change dynamically like (data=Survey_1 or data=Survey_2 or data=Survey_3)
I use #Reflection to get its value but failed to get its value
I use methods which I'm mentioning Below help me to sort out this problem.

`Field field   = DummyData.class.getDeclaredField(data);
 String JsonData = field.toString();`

and
`DummyData.class.getDeclaredField("Survey_1").toString()`

but this return package name, class name and string name but not return string value.
What I'm doing can some help me??

Comment: `field.toString();` is definitely not the way to get the field value. Looks like you have started reading how to use reflection, but didn't finish.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a Map<String, String>.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes u are right. I just started but its not end i'm learning, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value of a declared field is not as simple as that.

You must first locate the field. Then, you have to get the field from an instance of a class.

```
Field f = Dummy.class.getDeclaredField(“field”);
Object o = f.get(instanceOfDummy);
String s = (String) o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the simple `toString()` of the `Field` will actually invoke the `toString()` method of the `Field` object but **won't** access the value

You must do something like this:

```
Field field = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("someFieldName");
String someString = (String) field.get(null); // Since the field is static you don't need any instance
```

Also, beware that using reflection is an [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance) and [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002904/what-is-the-security-risk-of-object-reflection) operation. You should consider redesigning your system

Comment: Can you explain How "reflection" is expensive and dangerous operation?